# How to get callback when disconnect a non-connected device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can I get a disconnected callback (`BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange`) when I disconnected a BLE device which is not connected.

When I connect a BLE device (`BluetoothDevice.connectGatt`), if this device does not exist, it will take about 30 seconds(Android BLE connect timeout), and get the disconnected callback.

if I disconnect this device in this period(maybe at 10th second), I can't get any callback, even the timeout expired(30 seconds).

is any callback can I get in this situation?

I found this log:
"E bt_stack: [ERROR:bta_gattc_act.cc(292)] No such connection need to be canceled", but nothing seems to help.